# How to create a dynamic destination with BlazeDS

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds

looking for advice about how to structure the comms of a blazeds/flex game. What I'm trying to achieve is to have x no. of games occuring on the server each of which will contain 2 to 6 players. i think this will involve segmenting a feed, by creating a subtopic. eg game A gets filled with Player A + Player B, a dynamic destination gets created on the server side, and the new destination id gets returned to the clients. Not sure if I have that correct - to give some further background - the main server side code for a 2 player setup is here

[Connecting multiple flex clients to a single java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335491/connecting-multiple-flex-clients-to-a-single-java-class)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

[Creating runtime remoting destinations in BlazeDS and LiveCycle Data Services](http://quetwo.com/2011/05/15/creating-runtime-remoting-destinations-in-blazeds-and-livecycle-data-services/)